# Angular js- How to call directive methods inside controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs-directive

I have the directive named "student" and the problem is that i m not able to access the methods inside the directive,for instance i have to call the method "setText" in my controller,how do i do it?

```
angular.module('sampleApp')
        .directive('student', ['appConfig', '$filter', function(appConfig, $filter) {
          var template  = appConfig.DIRECTIVE_BASE_URL +'/demo/student.html';

          return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {

              $scope.setText = function(a){
                if(a.type === 'manual'){
                  return 'Manually Placed';
                } else {
                  return '';
                }
              };
            }],
            scope: {
              studentData: '=',
              studentName: '='
            },
            templateUrl: template
          };

        }]);
```

Comment: So you want to call `setText` before `return` in student directive?

Comment: it can be after return, just that i want to know how to call the method in the controller

Answer (score 0):

You can define `setText` inside of student directive.

```
angular.module('sampleApp')
       .directive('student', ['appConfig', '$filter', function(appConfig, $filter) {
         var template  = appConfig.DIRECTIVE_BASE_URL +'/demo/student.html';

         const setText = function(a) {
           if(a.type === 'manual') {
             return 'Manually Placed';
           } else {
             return '';
           }
         };

         return {
           restrict: 'E',
           replace: true,
           controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
             $scope.setText = setText;
           }],
           scope: {
             studentData: '=',
             studentName: '='
           },
           templateUrl: template
         };
       }]);
```

Comment: is there any way to call the methods without making any major change in directive

Comment: You can also move `setText` out of the directive, because it does not manipulate any directive specific data. I don't know what the major change you say means, but this reduces lines of the directive.